# Pandas, fast access by (multi)column value

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Basically, the question is "Does pandas have SQL-like multiindexing?"

In details,
I would like to add (multi) index of my DataFrame in order to access records with the given values of columns in the O(1) time.

The following script performs what I need, but not in O(1) time:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 0],[0, 0, 0]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df[np.logical_and(df['a'] == 0, df['b'] == 1)]
```

I wonder if there is a way to build a (multi) index of dataframe (let's say in in the O(N) time) and then access records in O(1) time.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty half-assed answer, but in case it is useful, I'll post anyway.

You can apply a multiindex to a dataframe with

```
df.set_index(['a', 'b'], inplace=True)
```

I have no idea what the time complexity is of the underlying implementation.

You can access row in a dataframe with a multiindex with the `ix` method as follows:

```
df.ix[(0, 1)]
```

I hope this is what you're looking for. Apologies if not.

Comment: This is what you want to be doing, I think this would be better if you used the OP's example :)

Comment: Another options is to use loc here (rather than ix), but much of a much-ness! :)

Comment: As far as I do not want to drop original columns

df.set_index(['a', 'b'], inplace=True, drop=False)

worked for me. 

The problem is that new index replaces the original one. I wonder if dataframe could keep several indexes.

Comment: A dataframe can have multiple indexes in the sense that the example above has two indexes in 'a' and 'b'. Is there is another column you want to include as an index on the frame, you can add it to the list in the arguments to `set_index`.